# How can I implement Android Dialog box?

Tags: android, dialog

How to implement the Dialog Box in my android project?

Comment: what problems do you have? Can you be more specify with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code where ever you want to show dialog..

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(Dialogs.this);
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.save1);
builder.setTitle("Save Your Work");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // do something.......
  }
 });
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // do something.......
  }
 });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: you can download the image to add to dialog..

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
            DB.open();
            Cursor c = DB.getContact("1"); 
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    Display(c);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            DB.close();
            String checkPass = pass.getText().toString();
            if(checkPass.equals(getpass)){
                startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this,Main.class));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong PassWord", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for simple AlertDialog or Dialogbox?

Example AlertDialog :

```
         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Borc.this);
                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Eraser");
                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                // Setting Icon to Dialog
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.remove);
                // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dataBase.borclar.delete(String.valueOf(tableHelper.getSelectedRowId()));
                    }
                });
                // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to start with android dialogs is reading the docs: [Android Dialog Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). They describe the various types of dialogs and how you can implement them in your app.

If you have a specific problem please show us your code and ask a correct question.